# Slice an array with an inline PDO query

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm trying to slice an array but getting an error "**array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array**"

Will appreciate any help!

```
    foreach(array_slice(($pdo->query($query)), 0, 3) as $row_Results) {
       $pic_id = $row_Results['pic_id'];
```

Comment: That's because `$pdo->query($query)` returns a PDOStatement object on success, not an array. RTM, [http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)

Comment: Well, the error seems pretty self-explanatory. Try `var_dump($pdo->query($query));`, you'll see that `PDO::query` returns an object, as explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to slice an array returned by SQL query - this should be done in the query itself

```
 foreach($pdo->query("$query LIMIT 3")) as $row_Results) {
   $pic_id = $row_Results['pic_id'];
```

will do the trick.